# Im doing a JavaScript CodeHS course, but what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Im doing intro to JS in a site called CodeHS. I believe I did the assignment its asking of me right but it says its wrong?

Here is what it wants me to do:

[image: What it wants me to do]

Here is what I did:

[image: What I did]

Heres what I apparently got wrong:

[image: What I got wrong???]

Ive run this code many times and it worked flawlessly, so why does it give me these errors?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Post CODE, not PICTURES of code

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a blank line inside the end of your while block, which also accounts for the line number. You should check the **IMPORTANT** note on the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jorge. You need to include the new line character '\n' at the end of the appropriate print statements, for the sake of the marking program. Try it like this:

```
while(numItems > 0) {
        println('We have ' + numItems + ' in inventory.');
        var buy = readInt('How many items would you like to buy?');
        if(buy <= numItems) {
            numItems -= buy; 
            println('Now we have ' + numItems + ' left.' + '\n');
        } else {
            println('There is not enough in inventory for that purchase.' + '\n');
        }
    }
```